# Why is my NYC Code coverage not working with ESM?

Tags: istanbul, ecmascript-next, es6-modules

I have the following code...

App.mjs

```
import express from "express";
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

class CommunicationsApplication{
  constructor() {
    this.app = CommunicationsApplication.getExpress();
    this.app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello World!')
    })

    this.app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
  }
  static getExpress(){
    return express()
  }
}
```

App.spec.mjs

```
import {CommunicationsApplication} from "./App.mjs";
import sinon from "sinon";
import {expect} from "chai";

it('Testing to see if test works', () => {
  const result = {
    get: sinon.fake(),
    listen: sinon.fake()
  }
  sinon.stub(CommunicationsApplication, 'getExpress').callsFake(()=>result)
  new CommunicationsApplication();
  expect(result.get.callCount).to.eq(1);
  expect(result.listen.callCount).to.eq(1);
})
```

package.json

```
"type": "module",
...
"test": "nyc mocha --recursive './lib/**/*.spec.mjs' --require esm"
```

But when I run I see...

```
  ✔ Testing to see if test works
```

Why is my code coverage not working?

```
  1 passing (4ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Not going to accept this answer but this does work...

```
"test": "c8 mocha --recursive './lib/**/*.spec.mjs' --require esm"
```

Answer (score 0):

NYC does not yet support Node native ESM. See https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/1287

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jackie, this worked for me. Using your example:

```
"test": "c8 mocha './tests/**/*.test.js' --exit"
```